# Passing iterator into function

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have the following code which is being used to find the weakest target out of a vector which is a vector containing a pointer to all the active units. I am trying to create an iterator that will go through each unit and pass it to another function called can_attack(Unit &u, Unit &v) which takes two units and measures if they are close enough to each other to attack.

On compilation I am getting the following error "error: reference to type 'const Unit' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'Unit *const'". I understand that I am passing in the wrong type of variable but am unsure how to turn the iterator into a const Unit. Thanks for any help

```
void World::enemies_within_attack_range(const Unit &u,
                                    vector<Unit*> &targets) const
{
  targets.clear();
  vector<Unit*>::const_iterator it=units.begin();
  for(it;it!=units.end();it++){
    if((*it)->team != u.team){
        if(can_attack(u,(*it))){
            targets.push_back(*it);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: You might want `can_attack(u, *(*it))`.

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you. One other quick question.. my for loop is generating an error that expression result is unused.. Why would that be? is the expression result not used in the for loop?

Comment: What is *expression result*? Which part is it in the code you showed?

Comment: The error I am receiving is 

:warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
      for(it;it!=targets.end();it++){

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in can_attack call and the parameter const Unit &u.
The call has to be corrected as songyuanyao mentioned: can_attack(u,*(*it)).
But this is not the only problem.
There are three options:

1. instead of const Unit &u, declare u as Unit & u;
2. instead of can_attack(Unit &u, Unit &v), declare it as can_attack(const Unit &u, Unit &v) if possible;
3. (this is probably the worst option) use call can_attack(const_cast < Unit& > (u),*(*it)).

The choice is yours.